# Opencart Search page as SEO url

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

Trying to get my search results page SEO-friendly .. seems so basic, yet my tags rewrite rule is conflicting it.

(Which also uses the `product/search` router) -- disabling the tags rewrite, search still doesn't seem to work properly.. it shows whatever it wants, even if I search a nonexistent item. (This behavior doesn't occur under the normal index.php?route=product/search URL)

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]*)$ index.php?route=product/search&tag=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ index.php?route=product/search&search=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php:

```
                    } elseif ($data['route'] == 'product/search' && $key == 'tag') {

                    $url .= '/tags/' . str_replace(' ','-',$value);

                    unset($data[$key]);

                } elseif ($data['route'] == 'product/search' && $key !== 'tag') {

                    $url .= '/search/' . str_replace(' ','-',$value);

                    unset($data[$key]);
                    //....
```

Is there any way to rewrite both of these routes without choosing one or the other?

Using Opencart 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

**catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php**

**find:**

`$this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';`

**add:**

```
if (strpos($this->request->get['_route_'], 'tag/') !== false) {
                            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/search';
                            $this->request->get['tag'] = str_replace('tag/','',$this->request->get['_route_']);
                        }
                        elseif (strpos($this->request->get['_route_'], 'search/') !== false) {
                            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/search';
                            $this->request->get['search'] = str_replace('search/','',$this->request->get['_route_']);
                        }

                    else {
                        $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';
                    }
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)$ index.php?route=product/search&tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&search=$1 [L]
```